# Decode/encode dictionary keyed by Date

Tags: swift, codable

Trying to encode/decode a dictionary that has `Date` as key, yields some surprising results.

The following code illustrates the behaviour:

```swift
let data = """
{ "20210507": "Person1", "20210508": "Person2" }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

try print(decoder.decode([Date: String].self, from: data))
```

Naively, one would think the decoding would succeed, however that's not the case, we are thrown the following error:

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>,
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], 
debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

So the decoder is told to decode a dictionary, by it somehow expects an array.

Moving to the encoding side:

```swift
let dict: [Date: String] = [Date(): "Person1",
                            Date().addingTimeInterval(86400): "Person2"]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

let data = try encoder.encode(dict)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

This works, however it outputs this:

```
["20211007","Person1","20211008","Person2"]
```

, which explains the error received before when attempting to decode a dictionary (aka a JSON object).

To make sure about the behaviour, I replaced the decoding data by

```
["20210507", "Person1", "20210508", "Person2"]
```

, and the decoding succeeded with no other changes in the decoding code from the first snippet.

So, it seems that when dealing with dates as dictionary keys, the decoder wants arrays of key+value pairs, instead of the dictionary.

Are there ways to make it work with the standard `Codable` infrastructure?

The alternative would be to decode `[String: String]`, and to parse the dates afterwards, wondering if there's a cleaner, more "Codabe-ish" alternative, though.

Comment: The issue here is that the decoder `dateDecodingStrategy` is only applicable to values and not keys so that is why your dictionary fails but your array works

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it makes sense if the strategy applies only to values, but in that case why does the decoder/encoder make the transformation between a dictionary and an array, shouldn't it throw another kind of error in this case?

Comment: I can't explain the behavior of the encoder but the decoder never transforms the result to an array.

Comment: The decoder also transforms, the JSON array to a Swift dictionary, so it still does things behind the scenes.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there. Which array is that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the array from the last code snippet `["20210507", "Person1", "20210508", "Person2"]` - this one is successfully decoded to a `[Date: String]`

Comment: Sorry, I had a line commented out so that's why it didn't work for me. So this is the same kind of behavior as for the encoder then and I don't understand the logic behind it (array->dictionary) but it makes senses that the date formatter works here.

Comment: there is a good explanation of the subject here: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/codable-swift-dictionaries/

Comment: [SE-0320](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0320-codingkeyrepresentable.md) will provide a solution to this issue via the `CodingKeyRepresentable` protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CodingKeyRepresentable` was released in Swift 5.6, which now allows decoding/encoding `Date` keyed dictionaries using `Codable`.

For more info, see [SE-0320](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0320-codingkeyrepresentable.md).

[Swift 5.6 was released on 14th March 2022](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.6-released/). When using Xcode, you need at least Xcode 13.3 to use Swift 5.6.