# Why JSONDecoder doesn't work with a date format?

Tags: json, swift, date-formatting, codable

I have a simple structs to represent a JSON about a stock:

```
struct Share: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
        case prices = "Time Series (Daily)"
    }
    var metaData: [String: String]
    var prices: [Date: TradingDay]
}

struct TradingDay: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case open = "1. open"
        case close = "4. close"
        case high = "2. high"
        case low = "3. low"
    }
    
    enum DecodingErrors: Error {
        case canNotMakeDouble
        case invalidCodingKeys
    }
    
    var open: Double
    var close: Double
    var high: Double
    var low: Double
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) else {
            throw DecodingErrors.invalidCodingKeys
        }
        
        guard let open = try? Double(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .open)),
              let close = try? Double(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .close)),
              let high = try? Double(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .high)),
              let low = try? Double(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .low)) else {
            throw DecodingErrors.canNotMakeDouble
        }
        
        self.open = open
        self.close = close
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
    }
}
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-07-01",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2022-07-01": {
            "1. open": "141.0000",
            "2. high": "141.6700",
            "3. low": "139.2600",
            "4. close": "141.1200",
            "5. volume": "4012106"
        },
        "2022-06-30": {
            "1. open": "139.5800",
            "2. high": "142.4600",
            "3. low": "139.2800",
            "4. close": "141.1900",
            "5. volume": "4878020"
        },
```

and so on.

I'm trying to decode this with the following code:

```
if let (data, _) = try? await URLSession.shared.data(for: request) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
                
    do {
        let share = try decoder.decode(Share.self, from: data)
        print(share.metaData)
        print(share.prices)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

But all I see is just an error.
When I make a prices dictionary (7th row) `[String: TradingDay]` type, it works appropriately.

Why doesn't it decode the dates, though I passed in the date format?
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please show the exact error message.

Comment: Note that the date is a key and not a value and I am pretty sure the date decoding strategy only applies to values.

Comment: Which Swift and Xcode version are you using? [You'll need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71160979/4667835) Swift 5.6 and Xcode 13.3 to be able to decode `Date` keyed JSON Dictionaries.

Comment: @MartinR `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

Comment: @DávidPásztor Xcode 13.4.1 Swift 5.6.1

Comment: @JoakimDanielson hence, implementing the custom init(from:) is the only option, right?

Comment: `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)` And I'd avoid `try?`, prefer a `do` `catch`, even for rethrowing your own custom error with less info, but print the real thrown error in console.